# Jquery Double Quote are replaced by "&quote"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
var text = "{time: 9.5, text: &quot;this&quot;},                                              
{time: 3, text: &quot;is&quot;},
{time: 5,text: &quot;so&quot;},
{time: 7, text: &quot;cool&quot;}";
abc = text.replace(/&quot;/g, '\"');
</script>
```

> Error = Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

desired Output

```
      {time: 9.5, text: "this"},
      {time: 3,  text: "is"},
      {time: 5,text: "so"},
      {time: 7,  text: "cool"}
```

Comment: You seen to have some sort of JSON type object, why not treat it as such?  Seems like there's some strange steps going on to get to this point.

Comment: This isn't a JS problem, it's an encoding issue with how you're fetching/saving that object. We need to see what generates this data.

Comment: How about? `var text = [{ time: 9.5, text: "this"},                                              
{time: 3, text: "is"},
{time: 5, text: "so"},
{time: 7, text: "cool"}];
var abc = JSON.stringify(text);`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't allow strings to be separated over multiple lines, you either need to have the string all on one line like i've shown below or join multiple individual strings (on individual lines) using `+`

```
var text = "{time: 9.5, text: &quot;this&quot;},{time: 3, text: &quot;is&quot;},time: 5,text: &quot;so&quot;},{time: 7, text: &quot;cool&quot;}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your whole string in one line like this:

```
var text = "{time: 9.5, text: &quot;this&quot;},{time: 3, text: &quot;is&quot;},{time: 5,text: &quot;so&quot;},{time: 7, text: &quot;cool&quot;}";
```

and see the results.

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of object.

```
    var text = [
      {time: 9.5, text: "this"},                                              
      {time: 3, text: "is"},
      {time: 5,text: "so"},
      {time: 7, text: "cool"}
   ];
```

By example :

`text[0].time;` 
will return 9.5

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have new lines in your strings. JavaScript doesn't support new lines in the middle of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this technique to create multi variable lines easily.

```
var json = function(){/*
[
    {   "time" : "9.5", "text" : "this"},
    {   "time" : "3",  "text" : "is"},
    {   "time" : "5", "text" : "so"},
    {   "time" : "7",  "text" : "cool"}
]

*/}.toString().slice(14,-3);

json = JSON.parse(json)

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. As others pointed out string must be in one line.
2. Your string is not a valid js object

```js
var text = "{time: 9.5, text: &quot;this&quot;}, {time: 3, text: &quot;is&quot;}, {time: 5,text: &quot;so&quot;}, {time: 7, text: &quot;cool&quot;}";
var object =  JSON.parse("[" + text.replace(/&quot;/g, '\"').replace(/time/g, "\"time\"").replace(/text/g, "\"text\"") + "]");
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a text variable in there and the content of this variable is defined as text = "text-content". It inside text-content you use double quotes, then you will end up with the error you see. Replace those double quotes with single quotes in this line:

```
abc = text.replace(/&quot;/g, "'");
```

Also, you need to remove the extra spacing (i mean the new lines within the text variable) to make this happen.

```js
var text = "{time: 9.5, text: &quot;this&quot;},{time: 3, text: &quot;is&quot;},{time: 5,text: &quot;so&quot;},{time: 7, text: &quot;cool&quot;}";

abc = text.replace(/&quot;/g, "'");
console.log(abc)
```